# Не могу установить JDK 8 для NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

**Мои действия:**

1. захожу на [сюда](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Качаю NetBeans
3. включаю установщик
4. NetBeans устанавливается, но сам `JDK 8` не устанавливается и выдает ошибку (скриншот)

Вопрос как это исправить? Если `JDK 9` устанавливается хорошо, а `JDK 8` нет!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
В показать подробности проблемы:
Сигнатура проблемы:
  Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH
  Имя приложения:   jdk-8u151-windows-x64.exe
  Версия приложения:    8.0.1510.12
  Отметка времени приложения:   59af7b30
  Имя модуля с ошибкой: jdk-8u151-windows-x64.exe
  Версия модуля с ошибкой:  8.0.1510.12
  Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 59af7b30
  Код исключения:   c0000005
  Смещение исключения:  0000000000036411
  Версия ОС:    6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Код языка:    1049
  Дополнительные сведения 1:    eca3
  Дополнительные сведения 2:    eca3c8ed148a97d8518ea99879403d4b
  Дополнительные сведения 3:    521b
  Дополнительные сведения 4:    521bf99c570bd4c753f5383de9084c41

Ознакомьтесь с заявлением о конфиденциальности в Интернете:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

Если заявление о конфиденциальности в Интернете недоступно, ознакомьтесь с его локальным вариантом:
  C:\Windows\system32\ru-RU\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Удалите один из вопросов, не нужно засорять сайт одинаковыми вопросами, их все равно закроют

Comment: Viacheslav Vedenin, а у тебя есть хоть какое-то разумное обьяснение по данной проблеме?

Comment: А у вас система точно 64 битная? Попробуйте ставить в режиме совместимости или админа. Если не поможет поставьте openJDK, на Oracle JDK свет клином не сошелся

Comment: точно 64 битная. щас попробую... хоть уже весь инет пролазил и не чего не нашел.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html -  тут есть 8u152 версия. Попробуйте ее или вообще версию для 86 процесоров. [холивар]А вообще ставьте IDEA и не мучайтесь... :))) [/холивар]

Comment: ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!! Тему можно закрывать.

Comment: Тогда поставьте на ответе галочку, что он принят, тогда все будут видеть, что вопрос решен. А какой именно пункт сработал?

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте, что у вас система точно 64 битная и в любом случае можете попробовать версию для 86 систем, хуже не будет,
2. Попробуйте запускать в режиме совместимости или админа, может помочь,
3. Возьмите версию 8u152 с [официального сайта](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), возможно эта ошибка там исправлена,
4. Если ничего не поможет, то можете взять OpenJDK Early-Access Builds версию (8u162 b03) [отсюда](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/)
5. В конце-концов, есть еще виртуалки, Live-CD диски линукса, где все может встать нормально, плюс NetBeans не единственная IDE, ту же IDEA возьмите вместо него, она намного более популярна на мой взгляд в проф. разработке,

Comment: Что касается openJDK, так его даже в линухе все стремятся заменить на oracle сразу же.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить jdk предыдущих версий. Установите правильно системные переменные. Проверьте 'java -version'. У меня Netbeans 8.1, работает с java версии 1.8. А вообще всё должно работать "из коробки". Проверьте на вирусы. Скачайте заново Nenbeans  и переустановите. Выберите "NetBeans with JDK 8" - она уже с JDK.  Выберите правильно платформу.

Answer (score 1):

Не мучайтесь с установкой Oracle JDK 8 именно для NetBeans, всё равно оно друг с другом не работает корректно, будет постоянно зависать и вылетать. Если вы точно планируете использовать NetBeans, предлагаю сразу поставить OpenJDK 8 или IBM Java SDK 8. Более новые версии Java для NetBeans 8 тоже применять не советую. 
Следует знать, что JDK не обязательно устанавливать инсталлятором, достаточно скопировать уже установленную папку с другого компьютера и прописать на вашем пути (PATH) и переменные окружения (JAVA_HOME), хотя это именно для NetBeans не обязательно. Еще можно попробовать установить, т.н. NetBeans Bundle, где JDK входит в состав самого дистрибутива NetBeans. См. [JDK 8u171 with NetBeans 8.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html)